# Can we choose columns in the table using a CASE subquery inside the SELECT in SQL?

Tags: sql, r, select, case

I have one main table and two support table. I need to extract information from all three tables into one table. However, the two support table have conflicting information. Thus, in the big table, only certain rows should have the value from one of the support table while others should have the value from the other support table. I would like to choose the data inputted base on some condition using a CASE statement

This sql code is within an R language code for other purposes. But the sql code is independent and no errors are related to the R code. The A.A11 and C.C1 are all type character while A.A12 and C.C1 are all numeric.

```
"SELECT ",
                 "A.A1, A.A3,",
                 "CASE",
                 "WHEN A.A12 = 0 THEN C.C6, C.C7",
                 "ELSE B.B6, B.B7",
                 "END",
                 "FROM ((A",
                 "INNER JOIN B",
                 "ON A.A12 = B.B1)",
                 "INNER JOIN C",
                 "ON CAST(A.A11 AS varchar(10)) = CAST(C.C1 AS varchar(10)))"
```

```
Warning in sqlExecute(con, query, sqlParams, fetch = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE) :
  42000 102 [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near ','.
Warning in sqlExecute(con, query, sqlParams, fetch = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE) :
  42000 8180 [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Statement(s) could not be prepared.
Warning: Error in sqlExecute: 42000 102 [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near ','.
42000 8180 [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Statement(s) could not be prepared.
[RODBCext] Error: SQLExecute failed
```

Comment: You need a case statement per field.  So, for example, you can't have `THEN C.C6, C.C7`

Comment: Please cut your input down to the minimum needed to illustrate the problem and then if A, B and C are the input data frames show the output of dput(A), dput(B) and dput(C) and also show the expected result.

Comment: Sorry, can you elaborate on what do you mean by per field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As near as I can tell, you want to do something along these lines...

```
SELECT
A.A1, 
A.A3,
CASE WHEN A.A12 = 0 THEN C.C6 ELSE B.6 END AS X6,
CASE WHEN A.A12 = 0 THEN C.C7 ELSE B.7 END AS X7,
FROM A INNER JOIN B ON A.A12 = B.B1
       INNER JOIN C ON CAST(A.A11 AS varchar(10)) = CAST(C.C1 AS varchar(10))
```

Comment: Can you tell me what does the X6 and X7 mean and why should it be there?

Comment: I tried this in my code (without the AS X6 and AS X7) and it doesn't work. Is this code friendly to use when trying to submit it as a query in R language?

Comment: This is ANSI SQL syntax, not sure how friendly to the R language.  Can you describe what doesn't work?  Doesn't compile?  Doesn't return what you want?

Comment: My mistake, It is the comma, or the lack of it, between the two case statements that caused the error

Comment: As someone else commented above, in your original query, you are mentioning two columns in one CASE statement with a comma between them ("WHEN A.A12 = 0 THEN C.C6, C.C7"), and in ANSI SQL you can't do that.  So, I just broke your CASE statement out into two CASE Statements.  The AS X6 & X7 is just to give a column name, for a column that may either hold C6 or B6, and C7 or B7, so, just to give it a neutral name of X but keep the 6 & 7.